# android canvas nine patch drawable fails

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, nine-patch, android-drawable

I'm trying to draw a NinePatchDrawable to a canvas,
but all what i get is a stretched normal drawable:

```
NinePatchDrawable test = (NinePatchDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test_orig);
Rect tbounds = new Rect(10, 10, 310, 110);
test.setBounds(tbounds);
test.draw(canvas);
```

original nine patch:
[image: original Nine Patch Drawable]

what it is supposed to look like:
[image: i want this]

what i get:
[image: what i get, but not want]

and before you ask:
yes, I have named the image `test_orig.9.png` and it is in the right folder.

Comment: can u post the image without 9 patch? let me apply 9 patch

Comment: you could open an image editor (e.g. gimp) and delete the border (< 1min)

Comment: this is not a image view.

Comment: Try to make the content area smaller(reduce the bottom and right black lines), it doesn't make sense for the content to fill the entire image.

Comment: but even the android sample images do it like this.., but i'll try

Comment: i tried, but it didn't help

Answer (score -1):

Remove the lines at the right and the bottom, only keep the top and the left of your current 9-patch image. That should work, hope it helps.

Comment: OK, so it's not about the 9-patch, it is something with your ImageView, please do NOT set any of the property `scaleType`, seems like your image is stretching to your ImageView. Hope this helps.

Comment: IT IS ***__NOT__*** AN IMAGEVIEW!!